# removing elements from a struct array

Tags: matlab

This is probably a super simple question, but here it is:

I have a <1xn> array of structs, and a vector of the indexes of the struct array that I want to remove.

So for example, if I have a removal vector of [2 6], it means I want to get rid of the 2nd and 6th struct in the array (and the array would be 2 elements shorter).

What is the clean, simple, matlab way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the name of your structure is `a`:

```
a([2 6])=[]
```

or more generally:

```
ind2rm=[2 6];
a(ind2rm)= []
```

PS: it also works for normal arrays or matrices (e.g. `A(:,[2 6])=[]`)

Comment: this is definitely the matlab way, not my solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need:

```
a = a(setdiff([1:n], [2, 6]))
```

a is the struct array and [2, 6] are the elements you want to remove.