# How to remove element from an array in the smartest vectorised one-line way matlab

Tags: matlab

I initialise an array in matlab:
`open=[];`
Then i add an element to it.
`open=[open;goal];` 
where `goal=[5 6];` is a row-vector. Now this `open` list is sent into a loop wherein either elements like `goal` are added or elements removed. I am concerned with only removing elements here. Say, i want to remove an element from the end of the list only, i.e. earlier `open` is of size 6 x 1, after deletion it should be 5 x 1, with the last element removed. How to achieve this in one line without writing a big code?

Comment: `open(end,:)=[]`? What other big code could there be?

Comment: @Divakar  comment is right, because if you concatenate vertically row vectors as you explained in your question, your array is going to be `[6x2]`, and not `[6x1]`. Unless you meant to add your elements all in a row, in which case you should add them as `open=[open,goal];`, in this case at some point you would get a `[1x6]` vector, and to remove the last element simply do `open(end)=[];`

Comment: I am new to vectorised ways so i was thinking of c++y type dumb idea of copying open again to a `temp` array of reduced size and renaming it `open`.

Comment: @Hoki No elements are added vertically like `open=[open;goal];`

Comment: Then by adding row vectors vertically, you will never have a `6x1` array, (_unless you transpose your `goal` before you add it to the array_). Note that this method of removing element works for any indice (not just the last). ex: `open(3)=[]` will remove the third element of the array. And it also work for cell arrays.

Comment: You can read these questions which all deal with a similar topic: [remove-elements-at-a-set-of-indices-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507843/remove-elements-at-a-set-of-indices-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-matlab), [removing-rows-by-indexing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968533/removing-rows-by-indexing/22968654#22968654), and [removing-elements-from-a-struct-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358977/removing-elements-from-a-struct-array)

Comment: FYI, if you're interested in speed, the simple `open(end,:)=[]` form may or may not be the fastest option. Often, something like `open=open(1:end-1,:)` will be faster, but this may depend on the size of your array, which elements are being removed, your computer/OS, and Matlab version.